Does anyone know if the xbox360 controller uses 16bits for joysticks in its hid?
I cannot get a single hid dumper to work on windows linux etc multiple boxes, different errors etc. It's such a pain.
I'm 99% sure that it's 16bit xy's but I can't verify. It's annoying because most gamepad hid examples are 8bit. I have a sniffer working and I'm sure I could modify it to dump the hids, but I can't even walk before I run here.

Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333210/how-to-tie-together-an-hid-usb-descriptor-and-the-usb-frames-actually-sent-on-th ... it shows how to use Wireshark to decode the HID Report Descriptor. That will tell you what the report format is.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088857/i-need-some-help-to-understand-usb-game-controllers-hid-devices may be relevant.  It has a link to Linux driver code - it may be easier to inspect that code than to reverse engineer the communication.

Yes, it is 16 bits.
People linking random SO articles does not help. I did not ask how to dump I asked if it's 16 bits. It is by the way. I got dumpers to work but none of the nonsense people linked.
Apparently, my post was not well received. I cannot ask any more of a direct question and I don't need pretentious SO mods and members to belittle it.
I know how to fish as they say. I do a lot every single day. I want someone to give me a fish sometimes.
